# How to use okhttp to create a stream of data and write into device in android

Tags: android

**What I am doing:** I am using a connection to download file from server and write into a storage

**What is happening:** Code is working

**What I am trying to do:** How to achieve the same using okhttp

```
 try {

            val url = URL(DICTIONARY_FILE_URL)
            val conection = url.openConnection()
            conection.connect()
            // getting file length

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            val input = BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192)

            // Output stream to write file
            val directoryPathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath.plus("/CNX/dictionary/")
            val dictionaryFileName = "DictionaryEN.quickdic"
            var f =  File(directoryPathName)

            if(!f.isDirectory) {
                f.mkdirs()
            }

            val output = FileOutputStream(directoryPathName.plus(dictionaryFileName))

            val data = ByteArray(1024)

            var count: Int? = 0

            while ({ count = input.read(data);count }() != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count!!)
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush()

            // closing streams
            output.close()
            input.close()
            isJobSuccess = true
            //sharedPreferences[IS_DICTIONARY_DOWNLOADED] = true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Exception",e.message)
            isJobSuccess = false
            //sharedPreferences[IS_DICTIONARY_DOWNLOADED] = false
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sample for Downloading a file with OkHttp **asynchronously**

   ```
   fun downloadFileAsync(downloadUrl: String) {
   val client = OkHttpClient();
   val request = Request.Builder().url(downloadUrl).build();
   client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
       override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
           Log.e("fail", e.printStackTrace().toString())

       }
       override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
           if (!response.isSuccessful) {
               Log.e("fail", "Download error")
           }else{
               // Output stream to write file
               val directoryPathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath.plus("/CNX/dictionary/")
               val dictionaryFileName = "DictionaryEN.quickdic"
               val f =  File(directoryPathName)
               if(!f.isDirectory) {
                   f.mkdirs()
               }
               val output = FileOutputStream(directoryPathName.plus(dictionaryFileName))
               response.body?.let {
                   output.write(it.bytes())
               }
               // flushing output
               output.flush()
               // closing streams
               output.close()

           }
       }
    })
   }
   ```
2. Sample for Downloading a file with OkHttp **synchronously**

   ```
   fun downloadFileSync(downloadUrl: String) {
   val client = OkHttpClient();
   val request = Request.Builder().url(downloadUrl).build();
   val response = client.newCall (request).execute();
   if (!response.isSuccessful) {
       Log.e("fail", "Failed to download file: " + response)
   }else {
       val directoryPathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath.plus("/CNX/dictionary/")
       val dictionaryFileName = "DictionaryEN.quickdic"
       val f = File(directoryPathName)
       if (!f.isDirectory) {
           f.mkdirs()
       }
       val output = FileOutputStream(directoryPathName.plus(dictionaryFileName))
       response.body?.let {
           output.write(it.bytes())
       }
       // flushing output
       output.flush()
       // closing streams
       output.close()
    }
   }
   ```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.5.0")
```